# Laravel Sail Share fails to host the site and keeps on buffering instead

Tags: laravel-sail

I just freshly installed laravel 8 using crul and now i am trying to use laravel's sail share to share my newly installed laravel 8 site but it is not working.
There seems no error. It keeps on showing as in the image in the given link but fails to load the fresh installed site.
Please help me through this.Have googled but hardly could find anything on this issue.